# C Delete a Node from a BST without inputting the Key

Tags: c, string, variables, key, binary-search-tree

I know how to delete a node the traditional way by using a key. However, I need to delete a node based off of a different variable (name), then find the key that matches that variable (name), and deleting all nodes that contain that variable (name). Assume that my insert/inorder/FindMin functions and #include are all present in my code. Here is my code:

```
int totalStud;

struct evil {
    int key;
    char name[21];
    struct evil *right;
    struct evil *left;
};



struct evil *Delete(struct evil* root, int key){

    if (root == NULL){
        return root;
    }else if(key<root->key){
        root->left = Delete(root->left, key);
    }else if(key>root->key){
        root->right = Delete(root->right, key);
    }else{
        if (root->left == NULL){
            struct evil *temp = root->right;
            free(temp);
            return temp;
        }else if(root->right == NULL){
            struct evil *temp =  root->left;
            free(temp);
            return temp;
        }
        struct evil *temp = FindMin(root->right);
        root->key = temp->key;
        root->right = Delete(root->right,temp->key);

    }
}

struct evil *DelFinder(struct evil* root, char name[21]){ //I tried several things here, but I don't know what to do here to make it work.
    if (root == NULL){
        return root;
    }
    if(strcmp(root->name, name)==0){
        root = Delete(root, root->key);
        return root;
    }else{
        if (root->left != NULL){
            DelFinder(root->left,name);
        }
        if(root->right != NULL){
            DelFinder(root->right,name);
        }
    }
    return root;
}



int main(void){
    struct evil* root = NULL;

    totalStud = 5;
    root = Insert(root, 1015, "Jack");
    root = Insert(root, 1002, "Bob");
    root = Insert(root, 1085, "Sow");
    root = Insert(root, 1088, "Knack");
    root = Insert(root, 1099, "Sow");

    inorder(root); //all the elements in the BST before deleting Sow

    for (totalStud = 5; totalStud !=-1; totalStud--){
        root = DelFinder(root, "Sow");
    }
    inorder(root); //all the elemennts in BST after deleting Sow

}
```

I know it's a problem with the DelFinder function, but I don't know the best way to write this to get it to work. I am trying to delete a element without using the key directly. ALSO if I were to ask for user input instead of making presets in the main function, what would be the best way to prevent them from making duplicate keys? as in asking the user to put a different key due to it already existing? (duplicate names are okay).

Comment: you are not being clear on what kind of output you are getting while running the code.

Comment: `free(temp);  return temp;`  (twice) you return the addres of the node you just deleted.

Comment: basically, I'm trying to delete based off of the string, so by having the string "Sow" in DelFinder, any node with "Sow" will be deleted. If I were to put Bob instead, that node would also be removed.